# UI Automator in project with minSdkVersion 9

Tags: android, testing, android-manifest, android-uiautomator

im trying to use UI Automator in my project with minSdkVersion 9 and of course it not work because it target API 18.

So Android Studio throws me this error:

```
Error:(5, 5) uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 18 declared in library ~/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support.test.uiautomator/uiautomator-v18/2.1.1/AndroidManifest.xml

Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.uiautomator.v18" to force usage

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 18 declared in library ~/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support.test.uiautomator/uiautomator-v18/2.1.1/AndroidManifest.xml

    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.uiautomator.v18" to force usage
```

I added to my Manifest the tag `<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.uiautomator.v18" />` but the error keep showing, i am doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file?

Answer (score 42):

If you use gradle you can add *another* Manifest to the `androidTest` build type which will get merged and does not affect your normal release / debug builds.

Add `app/src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml` to your project:

```
<manifest
    package="${applicationId}.test"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.uiautomator.v18"/>
</manifest>
```

This will *merge* the manifest with your normal one, not requiring to change your `minSdk`. PLease note, that this will probably crash if you try running UI Instrumentation Tests on sdk < 18.

By adding additional permissions to the `debug/AndroidManifest` you can also just add permissions for your tests like external storage if you don't regularly need them in your app. They will although be also available to your debug builds.

Comment: Are there any caveats using this approach? Thanks!

Comment: @NeonWarge none that I could think of other than things mentioned

Comment: This worked for me, I was having the same problem with the AndroidX version.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="${applicationId}.test">

<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android_libs.ub_uiautomator" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your app with minSdkVersion 18, however you can still switch to espresso.

Comment: Is there any way to specify `minSdkVersion` of 18 *only* for the androidTest flavor of the app?

Comment: Nothing that I know about. I think you would need to modify the gradle generated tasks and paly a lot to get it work.

Comment: According to flavor spec http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/build-system-concepts you can create flavor with proper minSdkVersion and build your tests with that flavor

Comment: what is espresso ?